# pyspark - setting spark.driver.extraJavaOptions from within Python code instead of spark-submit or spark-defaults

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I like to avoid using spark-submit and instead start my PySpark code with `python driver_file.py`

We have some proxy settings we set up using `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` with spark-submit or spark-defaults config file. I would instead like to set this option inside my Python code so I can run it with `python driver_file.py`

For some reason though when I try to do so with the following code, I cannot access the resource I am trying to access.  But by using the same option within spark-defaults I can.  What am I doing wrong?

```
sconf = SparkConf().set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").set('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', 'proxy_stuffness')
sconf.setAppName("something")
sc = SparkContext(conf = sconf)
print 'Config: ', sc.getConf().getAll()
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that some settings can not be set at runtime in your driver.  This depends somewhat on what type of environment/cluster you are running spark in and how you submit the application to it.  I believe the java options settings can only be set through `spark-defaults.conf` or on the command line call to `spark-submit`.

From the docs:

> Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related
>   to deploy, like “spark.driver.memory”, “spark.executor.instances”,
>   this kind of properties may not be affected when setting
>   programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, or the behavior is
>   depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it
>   would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit
>   command line options; another is mainly related to Spark runtime
>   control, like “spark.task.maxFailures”, this kind of properties can be
>   set in either way.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties

Comment: Adding to it,  this config cannot be set through the SparkConf directly in application because the driver JVM has already started at that point and so no settings given in SparkConf for JavaOptions will take effect.